# AngularJs Routing .cshtml files In MVC6

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want help in AngularJs routing with MVC6 .cshtml views
I create normal _layout for that's contains the application pattern.
And I reader Index.csthml to _layout using ReanderBody function.
Now I'm trying to add 'div' ng-view to render all other .csthml views using angularjs inside the Index.csthml but my code it's did not work.

AngularJs script that's I use as following:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.message = "My Message Is Super Awesome";
  });

angular.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/route1', {
            templateUrl: 'Home/BusinessLookup',
            controller: 'BusinessLookupController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }]);

angular.controller('BusinessLookupController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});
```

And Index.csthml file look like:

```
<div>
<a href="Home#/route1">Test</a>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    {{message}} <!--Here angular does not work-->

    <div ng-view=""></div>

</div>
```

MVC routing setup:

```
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
        }
```

Comment: remove Home from this '<a href="Home#/route1">Test</a>' and try again please

Comment: also, if possible then can you please post the error log from DEVELOPER TOOL of you browser?

Comment: for getting start you can even go with this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: DEVELOPER TOOL giving me error 'Uncaught TypeError: angular.config is not a function'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of an angular module for your app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and then use it like this:

```
app.controller(...

app.config(...
```

Hope this helps.